# Align a \addcontentsline entry in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I guess this is a simple question. I've added these two entries to the ToC with:
`\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{section_name}`
All I wanna do is align those two unnumbered sections with the numbered section, just like the drawed red line points out.

[image: Align those 2 texts]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look inside the `.toc` file you’ll see what commands are generating the lines in the table of contents. The numbered line will look like:

```
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {5}Conclusão}{65}{}%
```

while the unnumbered lines will look like:

```
\contentsline {section}{Referências}{66}{}%
```

It's the `\numberline` command that's reserving the space for the section number before the title.

It's not a bad idea to check what `\numberline` does before using it out of context. You can find the definition in the (lengthy) source code listing available with `texdoc source2e`:

```
\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1\hfil}}
```

Pretty much, it's just reserving space for its contents but not doing anything else.¹ So knowing that, you can change your `\addcontentsline` to be:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}section_name}
```

and get the same space reserved for those sections.

---

1. It's possible, if you're using a document class other than `article` that `\numberline` got redefined and wants to do something fancy with its value, but since you didn't specify that in the question, ‍♂️

Comment: Superb answer, I didn't pointed but I'm using overleaf service, so I don't really know how can I look into the .toc file, and yes, document class is article.